# dynamicly adds permissions to read/edit grafana dashboards in folder to users

Tags: grafana

I want to automatize creating users and adding permissisons. Is it possible in grafana, to dynamicaly adds permission to user based on AD group?

Lets say user inputs his data including AD group he is in, and the app will create folder, and sets read/edit permissions only to users that are in AD group (that can be any group )?

I know you can set viewer/editor/admin roles to people based on AD group in config file, but is it possible to do so dynamicaly, with their http api?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions for folders and permissions for dashboards using the Grafana HTTP API:

- [Folder Permissions API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/developers/http_api/folder_permissions/)
- [Dashboard Permissions API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/developers/http_api/dashboard_permissions/)

The logic, what permission should be set for which user, needs to be determined in your code (e.g. based on the user input you mentioned) before making the request.

Comment: but can i do it with AD groups?